# PythonAnywhere How to Enable Threads

Tags: python-2.7, pythonanywhere

I am always getting this:

```
you can enable thread by --enable-thread ...
```

Can anyone tell how to exactly do this?
Thanks.

```
2016-07-23 15:06:01 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
2016-07-23 15:06:01 thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
2016-07-23 15:06:01 uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/sockets/hassanalvi.pythonanywhere.com/socket fd 7
2016-07-23 15:06:01 Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27)  [GCC 4.8.2]
2016-07-23 15:06:01 *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
2016-07-23 15:06:01 Python main interpreter initialized at 0x146b720

*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
```

Comment: How are you running your script? Through bash? Threads are working for me

Comment: PythonAnywhere doesn't support threads in web apps, perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: I am using flask and when i start a thread it errors me this ...
2016-07-23 15:06:01 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
2016-07-23 15:06:01 thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
2016-07-23 15:06:01 uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/sockets/hassanalvi.pythonanywhere.com/socket fd 7
2016-07-23 15:06:01 Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27)  [GCC 4.8.2]
2016-07-23 15:06:01 *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
2016-07-23 15:06:01 Python main interpreter initialized at 0x146b720

Comment: Why do you want to enable threads?

Comment: If you don't want to use them, then you can ignore that message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately python anywhere doesn't support thread is a web server, [check out this article.](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/3627/) However, there is a fix if you just want [to run a task](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/LongRunningTasks).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but just like I stumbled across it searching for a solution, so might others.
In case you're one of these others, I just wanted to let you know that using `multiprocessing.Process` instead of `threading.Thread` worked like a charm in my case.
So if processes are ok for your scenario - mine was running a script in a flask app, but still responding in time to the post-request - this is a much simpler solution.